# Dynamically update html content plain JS

Tags: javascript, dynamic, appendchild

So I have a script bound in my index.html, which literally has to fetch an array of jsons from an api, then dynamically update my page when get response.

But as a result I'm getting an  as the only update of my page.

here is my script

```
fetch(url)
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then((resp) => {
    resp.results.forEach(item => {
        fetch(item.url)
            .then((response)=> response.json())
            .then((response) => pokeArr.push(response))
            .catch(console.log)
    })
}).catch(console.log)


const filler = () => {
    if(!pokeArr) return 0
    pokeArr.map((i,j)=>{
        return `<tr>${i.name}</tr>`
    })
}

const pokeindex = () => {
    document.getElementById('a').appendChild(document.createElement(filler()))
}
pokeindex()
```

When I'm consoling it, I can see in the console all the responses I get, so I'm at least doing the fetching part right.

Comment: What's `parberakan`? What's `pokeArr`?

Comment: Note that `document.createElement` doesn't accept HTML strings. It accepts the tag name of the single element to create (e.g., `document.createElement("div")`).

Comment: Side note: Your `fetch` call is missing an `.ok` check, details in [this post on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: parberakan is the old name of the pokeArr, which is an empty array, fixed that in my code, nothing changed

Comment: Please correct the code in the question, then. And where are you declaring that array?

Comment: Also note that nothing is waiting for your multiple `fetch` calls to complete before trying to do something (I think?) with the results.

Comment: `filler` returns `0` or `undefined`. You ignore the results of your `map()` call entirely.

Comment: fixed the code, pokeArr is declared right before the fetch, it's just an empty array

Comment: so how can i dynamically update the page?

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) This question is **far** to broad for SO's format.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues here:

1. You have `parberakan` in one place but `pokeArr` in another; in a comment you've suggested they're meant to be the same thing.
2. You don't declare `parberakan`/`pokeArr` anywhere in the quoted code.
3. Nothing in the quoted code is waiting for the various `fetch` calls to complete (not even the first, and esp. not the series of them in one of its `then` handlers).
4. The `fetch` calls aren't checking `.ok`; see [the post on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).
5. `document.createElement` doesn't accept HTML strings. It accepts the tag name of the single element to create (e.g., `document.createElement("div")`).
6. `filler` doesn't return the result of `map`.
7. Passing `console.log` directly to `catch` isn't 100% reliable.

At a rough guess, I suspect you want to do something like this (see comments), but I do recommend stepping back from your current task and working through some basic tutorials:

```
// Create these functions first
const filler = (pokeArray) => {     // Accept the array as a parameter
    if(!pokeArray) return null;     // Recommend null instead of 0 if the other return is an array
    return pokeArray.map((i,j)=>{   // Return the result of `map`
        return `<tr>${i.name}</tr>`;
    });
};

const pokeindex = (pokeArray) => {  // Accept the array as a parameter
    // I'm assuming the element with id="a" is a `table` or `tbody`
    document.getElementById('a').insertAdjacentHTML( // This accepts HTML
        "beforeend",
        fillter(pokeArray)
    );
}

fetch(url)
.then((resp) => {
    // Check .ok
    if (!resp.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + resp.status);
    }
    return resp;
})
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then((resp) => Promise.all(resp.results.map(item => { // Wait for all these to complete;
                                                       // result is an array of the
                                                       // resolution values
    return fetch(item.url)
        .then((response) => {
            // Check .ok
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + resp.status);
            }
            return response;
        })
        .then((response) => response.json());
})))
.then((pokeArray) => {
    // Now we have the array and can do something
    pokeindex(pokeArray);
})
.catch(error => { console.log(error); }); // Passing `console.log` directly isn't reliable
```

I may not have caught every last little thing, though. This is just to help get you pointed the right way.

Comment: The question is probably far too broad, though. I've voted to close, recommend others do the same.